# Validator for list box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, listbox

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lst_newGrpMembers" 
             DataValueField="Name" 
             SelectionMode="Multiple"
             Width="120px" 
             ToolTip="Press ctrl to select multiple users" 
             runat="server">
</asp:ListBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
                            runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="lst_newGrpMembers"
                            ErrorMessage="Atleast one member required" 
                            CssClass="Error" 
                            Text="*Atleast one member required"
                            ValidationGroup="CreateGroupValidationGroup">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I have a required field validator for a list box, it validates and shows error where there is no entry in the list box, but when I add item to the list box, it still shows error. When I select the list box item which I added and click submit it works fine. How to validate the list box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the `RequiredFieldValidator`, try setting `InitialValue` to empty string:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"          
    InitialValue=""
    ControlToValidate="lst_newGrpMembers" 
    ErrorMessage="Atleast one member required"  
    CssClass="Error"  
    Text="*Atleast one member required" 
    ValidationGroup="CreateGroupValidationGroup"> 
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of a list box are not sent to the server, only the selected item is. This is the way forms work in HTTP. Select your item after adding it or put it in a hidden form field (via script) to get sent to the server.

There are various ways to go about this via script. I did find this contro (I havent used it though) which I believe does this for you: http://www.metabuilders.com/Tools/DynamicListBox.aspx

This is also covered in more detail here: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1687079.aspx/1
where they select items on postback using jQuery:

```
function save() {
$("#lstFiles").each(function () {
      $("#lstFiles option").attr("selected", "selected");
});
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is validating whether or not there is a SELECTED value in ListBox. When you post it, probably, you will only receive the selected value for the ListBox. When you add the items to the ListBox, set the SELECTED property to true, and disable the ListBox to avoid unselection.

Like this:

```
    ListItem myItem = new ListItem();
    myItem.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    myItem.Selected = true;
    ListBox1.Items.Add(myItem);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I cant disable It since I have a button to remove the items from the list box. Is it possible to have a selected item all the time

Comment: Your button removes all items or just one at a time?

Comment: Even if I select multiple items the button will remove only 1 item in a single click

Comment: You could provide a DropDownList to remove items. Or you could select items programatically prior to submit. Maybe with some AJAX. Or javascript if you know what type of control dos ListBox transforms when loaded on a browser.